# ASP.NET MVC3 and Entity Framework- one-to-many relationship in one view

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm learning MVC 3 and i've got a problem with one thing.

I have two tables in my model (Gallery and Image). These tables ar related (one-to-many) by GalleryId (1 gallery - many images).

On Gallery -> Details view i would like to insert gallery details(which is simple) and one more thing - list of images from this gallery. I have no idea how to do it.
Here are classes from this model:

```
public partial class Gallery
{
    public Gallery()
    {
        this.Images = new HashSet<Image>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
public partial class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int GalleryId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UploadedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual Gallery Gallery { get; set; }
}
 public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Gallery> Galleries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: This is more a question regarding Entity Framework than MVC

Comment: Looks more like NHibernate.... When you want the images on the view, can you not do a foreach loop as Images is a property of Gallery?  foreach (var image in Galleries.Images) and loop through the images that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the detailview, you use the Gallery as your model (in the controller you return the desired gallery `return ActionResult View(service.GetGallery(id));`

and in the view you have a loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Images.Select((model, index) => new { index, model }))
{
    <div>@(item.index). @item.model.Name </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to is to pass it in the Model you're passing to the Details view.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
     var item = //get gallery item from database

     item.ImagesReference.Load();

     return View(item);
}
```

in your view, you can do something like:

```
<ul>
    <%: if (Model.Images != null) foreach(var item in Model.Images) { %>
         <li> <%: item.Name %> </li> 
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

You could also just pass a list via ViewData, but I think passing it in your Model is tidier as it does not require any other variable to be set, EF does that for you in the Model.

Note: Some names I typed might be off, but Intellisense will give you the correct names as EF has already generated those objects. I hope you understand the basic idea I'm trying to explain :-)